# How To Export Variables From module.exports Into An External Module In Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, node-modules, es6-modules

I am trying to import some variables (mapbox variables) from `config.js` into `controller.js` in order to use them to make HTTP calls. My problem is that when I `console.log(...)` those variables, they are `undefined`. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks.

```js
// config/index.js
module.exports = {
  mapBoxAPIBase:'https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5',
  mapBoxKey:"pk.xxxxxxxxx",
}

// controllers/controller.js
const { mapBoxAPIBase, mapBoxKey } = require('../config');
module.exports = {
  Location: {
      fwdGeocoding: async (address) => {
          console.log(mapBoxAPIBase);
          console.log(mapBoxKey);

      }
  }

}
```

**Results**

```
console.log(mapBoxAPIBase); => undefined
console.log(mapBoxKey); => undefined
```

Comment: Sorry, posted an answer and then realized I'd misread your question. Please could you provide your directory structure?

Comment: Hey. yes sure.  `config => index.js` and `controllers => controller.js`. config and controllers folders are on the same level

Comment: {
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 13,
  "colno": 1
}

Comment: Not able to run your code

Comment: I think it's because it's server-side code. But the struggle is real here tho

Comment: Sorry, wrong again. One day I'll stop jumping to conclusions!
In your post, you wrote `config.js`. Is that true? Or is that file `index.js`?

Comment: the file is index.js, but because of es6, you can either omit the `.js` or `index`. This works because the file is called `index`. That is why I didn't have to do `require('../config/index.js')` or `require('../config/index')`

Comment: OK, so it's actually `index.js` which contains the code `module.exports = { mapBoxAPIBase:...`?

Comment: yes the code resides in index.js

Comment: The only other thing I can think is that maybe, in your wider project structure, you have a cyclic requirement. In such a case, node.js considers the offending module to be empty while it resolves the rest of the cycle. To see this demonstrated, add `console.log( require( "../controllers/controller.js" ));` at the top of `config/index.js`; you should see it log `{}`, not `{ Location: ...`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211607/discussion-between-jack-robinson-and-alljs).

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. When declaring a variable inside the `module.exports`, make sure you declare a function that `returns` something; otherwise, when you try to import the variable into another module it will be `undefined`

```js
//config.js
module.exports = {
  mapBox: () => {
    return {
      mapBoxAPIBase:'https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5',
      mapBoxKey:"pk.xxxxxxxxx",     
    }
 
  }

}

//controller.js
const { mapBox } = require('../config');
module.exports = {
  Location: {
    fwdGeocoding: async (address) => {
      console.log(mapBox());

    }
  }

}

//Results

{
  mapBoxAPIBase:'https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5',
  mapBoxKey:"pk.xxxxxxxxx",     
}
```

Comment: It's strange tho, because I have used this config file multiple times to load my variables. But for some reasons, it stop exporting variables. My guess is that there are too many variables being exported and it is polluting the namespace? I am not sure. But looks like the option to use a `function` that returns something works so far.

Comment: This isn't necessary; I've reproduced your original code locally and it's working fine. Still trying to work out why it wasn't working on your machine...

Comment: I will welcome any other alternatives here. It makes no sense why it will work and then when I add other variables, it stops to work. I don't understand that. Thanks for helping me figure this out.